# How do I make my logo into a button in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui

I'm trying to get an image of a logo to be a button. I'm new to Swift/SwiftUI and the resources I've found so far seem to be outdated information. I have the image loaded in to see that I can get the image in there, and I've created a button in the location I want it, I just want to combine the two. Code is below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image("logo1024")
            .resizable()
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
            
        


        
        Group{
            
            Button(action: {
                print("tapped!")
            }, label: {
                Text("+")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .padding()
            })
        }.frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place image instead of Text into button (all other modifiers on your needs), like

```
    Group{
        
        Button(action: {
            print("tapped!")
        }, label: {
             Image("logo1024")
                .resizable()
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .padding()
        })
    }.frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
```